# esp32 idf multi-socket-server

Tags: c, sockets, server, esp32

It's my first post so ask for remotely anything if it can help and I didn't provide it.

My application requires multiple sockets being opened at once from Master, then the slaves connect to WiFi, and then to the sockets

Problem is: I have to make it "bulletproof" against constant reconnecting from slaves and i get Accept error:
E (23817) TCP SOCKET: accept error: -1 Too many open files in system
It appears when I reconnect client for 5th time, when Max Number of Open Sockets = 5 in menuconfig,

I disconnect clients from the server when they don't send anything in 1second -> then i assume they got DC-d.
I do it with close() procedure.

```
void closeOvertimedTask(void * ignore)
{
    while(1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < openedSockets;)
        {
            if(needsRestart[i] == 1)
            {
                ESP_LOGI("RESTARTING", " task#%d",i);
                //lwip_close_r(clientSock[i]);

                //closesocket(clientSock[i]);

                //ESP_LOGI("closing result", "%d", close(clientSock[i]));
                stopSocketHandler(i);
                needsRestart[i] = 0;
                //if(isSocketOpened[i])
                {

                }

                ESP_LOGI("close", "%d", lwip_close_r(clientSock[i]));
                isSocketOpened[i] = 0;

                xTaskCreate( handleNthSocket, "TCP_HANDLER", 10*1024, &(sockNums[i]) , tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &socketHandlerHandle[i]);
                configASSERT(socketHandlerHandle[i]);
                needsRestart[i] = 0;
            }

            if(isSocketOpened[i])
            {
                int diff = ((int)((uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time()) - lastWDT[i]) - 2*TCPWDT;

                if(diff > 0)
                {
                    if(isSocketOpened[i])
                    {
                        ESP_LOGI("I FOUND OUT HE DC-d","");
                        //closesocket(clientSock[i]);
                    }
                    ESP_LOGI("close", "%d", close(clientSock[i]));

                    stopSocketHandler(i);
                    isSocketOpened[i] = 0;

                    xTaskCreate( handleNthSocket, "TCP_HANDLER", 10*1024, &(sockNums[i]) , tskIDLE_PRIORITY, &socketHandlerHandle[i]);
                    configASSERT(socketHandlerHandle[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For each socket I run 1 task that is supposed to receive from that socket and act further.

For all of them I have an other task that checks last time a message arrived and restarts tasks when time has exceeded  (it's 2 seconds)

I need around 16 sockets opened in the final version so there is no room to have sockets that are still closing after Slave has restarted whole connection

1. How to properly close a Task with running recv() procedure in it to properly close Socket.
2. Is there a way to read from Server side that socket has been closed if WiFi hasn't realized STA DC-d
3. Is this about TIME_WAIT from tcp stack ?

Socket read code:

```
void handleNthSocket(void * param) // 0 <= whichSocket < openedSockets 
{
    int whichSocket =  *((int *) param);

    ESP_LOGI("TCP SOCKET", "%s     #%d", getSpaces(whichSocket), whichSocket);
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;

    while (1) 
    {
        if(needsRestart [whichSocket] == 0)
        {
            socklen_t clientAddressLength = sizeof(clientAddress);
            clientSock[whichSocket] = accept(sock[whichSocket], (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &clientAddressLength);
            if (clientSock[whichSocket] < 0) 
            {
                ESP_LOGE("TCP SOCKET", "accept error: %d %s", clientSock[whichSocket], strerror(errno));  //HERE IT FLIPS
                //E (232189) TCP SOCKET: accept error: -1 Too many open files in system

                isSocketOpened[whichSocket] = 0;
                needsRestart[whichSocket] = 1;
                continue;
            }
            //isSocketOpened[whichSocket] = 1;
            // We now have a new client ...

            int total = 1000;

            char dataNP[1000];
            char *data;
            data = &dataNP[0];

            for(int z = 0; z < total; z++)
            {
                dataNP[z] = 0;
            } 
            ESP_LOGI("TCP SOCKET", "%snew client",getSpaces(whichSocket));
            ESP_LOGI("          ", "%s#%d connected",getSpaces(whichSocket), whichSocket);
            lastWDT[whichSocket] = (uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time() + 1000000;
            isSocketOpened[whichSocket] = 1;
            // Loop reading data.


            while(isSocketOpened[whichSocket]) 
            {
                /*
                if (sizeRead < 0) 
                {
                    ESP_LOGE(tag, "recv: %d %s", sizeRead, strerror(errno));                
                    goto END;
                }

                if (sizeRead == 0) 
                {
                    break;
                }
                sizeUsed += sizeRead;
                */

                ssize_t sizeRead = recv(clientSock[whichSocket], data, total, 0);
                /*for (int k = 0; k < sizeRead; k++)
                {
                    if(*(data+k) == '\n')
                    {
                        ESP_LOGI("TCP DATA  ", "%sthere was enter", getSpaces(whichSocket));
                        //ESP_LOGI("TIME      ", "%d", (int)esp_timer_get_time());
                    }
                    //ESP_LOGI("last wdt", "%d", (int)lastWDT[whichSocket]);

                }*/


                lastWDT[whichSocket] = (uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time();
                int diff = ((int)((uint64_t)esp_timer_get_time()) - lastWDT[whichSocket]) - 2*TCPWDT;
                ESP_LOGI("last wdt", "%d, data = %s", (int)lastWDT[whichSocket], data);

                if(diff > 0)
                {
                    ESP_LOGI("last wdt", "too long - %d", diff);
                    isSocketOpened[whichSocket] = 0;
                }

                if (sizeRead < 0)
                {
                    isSocketOpened[whichSocket] = 0;
                }


                //TODO: all RX from slave routine
                for(int k = 0; k < sizeRead; k++)
                {
                    *(data+k) = 0;
                }



    //          ESP_LOGI("lol data", "clientSock[whichSocket]=%d, 
                /*if(sizeRead > -1)
                {
                    ESP_LOGI("TCP DATA: ", "%c", *(data + sizeRead-1));
                }
                else
                {
                    ESP_LOGI("TCP DC    ", "");
                    goto END;               
                }*/     



            }
            if(isSocketOpened[whichSocket])
            {
                ESP_LOGI("closing result", "%d", close(clientSock[whichSocket]));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you *closing* your sockets anywhere?

Sockets, no matter the platform, is usually a limited resource, and a resource that will be reused. If you don't close the sockets then the system will think that you still use then, and can't reuse those sockets for new connections (and on POSIX systems even opening *files* will be affected).

So close connections *immediately* when they are not needed any more.

Usually this is done by checking what `recv` and `send` returns: If they return a value less than zero an error occured and in most cases it's a non-recoverable errors, so connection should be closed. Even if it is a recoverable error, it's easier to close the connection and let the client reconnect.

For `recv` there's also the special case when it returns zero. That means the other end has closed the connection. That of course you need to close your end as well.

Answer (score 0):

this post solved all my problems
https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=911